# Variational autoencoder with (known) latent meaning

Tags: machine-learning, training-data, autoencoder

My Goal is to generate organic 3D-shapes within a closed volume conditioned and with the user-input of location. The volume is separated into 18 regions and I want the user to provide the information of which region is occupied by the shape with which percentage. This occupancy information is also part of my dataset, essentially it corresponds to the label of each shape.

The data-samples are only 44, so there is not a lot of variation in it.
I can overfit a VAE on my data-samples[VAE that learns organic shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2GiO.png). However encoding and decoding unseen shapes does not result in good reconstructions. For example, the occupancy of the resulting shape is not respected.

The initial Idea is to add the 18-dimensional occupancy information to the Decoder-input, together with the encoded latent-space.
The Decoder should then ideally learn the meaning of the first 18-dimensions (in which region with which percentage) and combine it with the encoded shape information to produce better reconstructions.[Decoder that creates shapes with corresponding occupancy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGBkC.png)

Separately both nets can be trained well. A VAE which encodes shapes into a latent vector and decodes them, which however, performs poorly on unseen data (e.g. does not encode occupancy information), presumably due to low amount of data-samples. And a Decoder which takes as input a vector with occupancy information and a random latent-vector and reproduces a shape which is in the specified areas with the corresponding occupancy.

How can I combine both nets together without losing the reconstruction quality or the occupancy information?
Essentially, learn the latents with the Encoder and use a Decoder that recieves the latents and (!) a occupancy and decodes them into shapes with specified occupancies?
[Autoencoder that learns organic shapes with occupancy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CUJp.png)

First Idea:
train Decoder with random latents and generated occupancy on occupancy error -> Decoder that returns shapes in areas with specified occupancy. However not the organic shapes i need.

Then train them alternatingly:
train Encoder and Decoder on reconstruction error. Encoder receives shape, Decoder receives latent with occupancy label.
train Decoder on occupancy error. Decoder receives some generated occupancy labels with random latents.

However this results in competing performance. I.e. the reconstruction part affects the occupancy part negatively and the occupancy part affects the reconstruction part negatively.
In principle it should be possible to have both losses well. Ideally the encoding does not need to contain any information about the location, since the Decoder already receives it and returns some (not organic) shapes within that region. The latent should be used to provide information on this shape so it becomes organic.